# Convert a hex or rgb color to fecolormatrix values

Tags: css, svg, svg-filters

I know literally nothing about SVG but I have a script running on my site that toggles images between color and B+W by applying an svg color filter and then removing it on hover. The tone of the color appears to be set using a matrix of values shown below...

```
 <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"/>
```

My problem is that I want to change the color of the filter so that it has a very slight sepia tone instead of pure B+W as it currently is. I can't believe that nobody has created a RGB or hex color converter but google doesn't seem to turn one up - maybe I am searching for the wrong thing? How do I do this? I heard once that it is done in illustrator but I dont use illustrator. Is there an online converter or can it be done in photoshop?

Comment: take hex value(s), convert to RGB, then divide by 255. simple example `#FA0000` (a red color ) is 250/255 is 0.98039215686 so round to 2 dec  is `0.98`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mistake the function of a feColorMatrix. You don't get a single output color from a colormatrix, the output is dependent on the combination of R , G, and B colors.

[Read the web platform docs on feColorMatrix.](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/svg/elements/feColorMatrix)

You can play with sepia settings using [this color matrix demo](http://codepen.io/mullany/pen/qJCDk) I built.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but isn't the sepia filter just a single "uniform" block of color in itself instead of a detailed image I mean? I understand that it is a blend of RGB values, so why isn't there a simple way to convert an RGB color into a matrix value set?

Comment: In the general case, it's because, given a single known input vector (your input RGB color) and a single known output vector (your output RGB color) there is an unlimited number of matrices that can transform one to another. You have to provide at least 2 (and maybe 3, my linear algebra is rusty) input/output pairings to get a single solution. Sepia filters - as long as they're just tinted greyscales - are easier. If you know what color you want RGB(127,127,127) to convert to - you can derive the proper color matrix values easily using a bit of linear algebra.

Answer (score 1):

There is a webkit-filter that is, precisely, sepia.
It has a parament to specify the amount (of sepia filtering), and the equivalent is:

```
<filter id="sepia">
  <feColorMatrix type="matrix"
    values="(0.393 + 0.607 * [1 - amount]) (0.769 - 0.769 * [1 - amount]) (0.189 - 0.189 * [1 - amount]) 0 0
            (0.349 - 0.349 * [1 - amount]) (0.686 + 0.314 * [1 - amount]) (0.168 - 0.168 * [1 - amount]) 0 0
            (0.272 - 0.272 * [1 - amount]) (0.534 - 0.534 * [1 - amount]) (0.131 + 0.869 * [1 - amount]) 0 0
             0 0 0 1 0"/>
</filter>
```

info taken from [here](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/functions/sepia)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my problem is that I find the exact tone of the sepia filter to be too much for me - I need a sepia with just a touch more red and slightly less yellow int he mix so I wished to know how to convert an rgb color into a matrix value set.